# Session resets on redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-variables

My code is literally only:
    `Response.Redirect("~/SomeDirectory/Default.aspx");`

However it clears out the Session completely on the redirect. I even checked in debug mode to be sure the session still had its variable before the redirect and it does.

Any and all redirects used from "~/SomeDirectory/Default.aspx" and other pages go to their proper pages without causing the session to expire/reset.

Comment: Would you consider editing your question so it is clearer what is being asked?

Comment: Are you sure that the `Session` are not being overwrited in any page event of `~/SomeDirectory/Default.aspx`? Does the codebehind class inhertis another class? If yes, does this base class handle the page events?

Comment: @Marcus It does call another class to do a set of actions. But once those actions are completed, the Session data is still in memory. I have nothing overwriting the data on Default.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use an overloaded version of the Response.Redirect:

Response.Redirect("~/SomeDirectory/Default.aspx", false);

It will not terminate a current thread and maybe will solve your problem (http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/a8wa7sdt.aspx)